# Runtime-Class cast Exception when compiled the source with Ant script

Tags: java, ant, compilation, runtime-error

I am using ant and jdk-1.5_10 for compiling my source and creating a jar file. And the jar is created without any compilation errors.
But I am facing following during run time for the following code -
**Class Cast Exception --> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object**
(Note- I have not included complete code, only the one in which I am having doubt)

```
void someFunction(List<Object[]> result){
   Object[] resultObject = new Object[1];
   for (Object resultSet : result) {
      resultObject[0] = resultSet;
   }//end of for
}//end of function
```

I am getting an exception at the 3rd line (for (Object resultSet : result)).
But when i replace the class which contains above function that is compiled using eclipse then it executes without error's. Eclipse is also using jdk-1.5_10

I am unable to find out the reason for this. Is there any issue when i compile the source using ant script. Need help to find out the reason behind this scenario.

Thanks!!

Comment: Isn't each element of `result` an Object array? so try `for(Object[] resultSet : result)`

Comment: Hi Hunter!
Ya it is. But I want to know the reason why it does not thorw runtime exception when i use the class i.e compiled in eclipse and why it comes when using class compiled by ant script ??

Comment: I have edited my question which now has the cause of the exception also

Comment: I guess you are using same JDK while compiling and same JRE while running, right?

Comment: Are you running it in exactly the same way each time, the ant compiled version and the eclipse compiled version? Or are you running it differently (i.e. do you run the eclipse version from within eclipse?

Comment: 1. I run the eclipse version from within eclipse.
 2. And the jar that is created is present in the war file which is deployed on the tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your ant-generated jar from the command line, you are passing to "someFunction" a list of elements, and one of this elements is a Long, and your programs is expecting it to be a Object[]. If you try with same input, both cases (command line and eclipse) should do the same.

However, I think you are not iterating correctly, each object in the list is an array (you are using object):

```
void someFunction(List<Object[]> result){
    Object[] resultObject;
    for (Object[] resultSet : result) {
        System.out.println(resultSet); // Is an Object[]
       resultObject = resultSet;
    }//end of for
 }//end of function
```

Comment: if you still have problems with the same exact code and same input (very strange case), post your full code, please.

Comment: Ok I got the explanation that you gave. But I want to find out the reason when i run the eclipse version of class using eclipse there is no error but when i run the ant generated class file there is this exception.